# Displaying an image in Angular that was saved on node.js backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

So I have a question concerning security. Imagine that I have uploaded a picture of an animal to the server. I have saved `1545419953137bear.jpg` on the backend in my uploads folder where I save all my images.

On the frontend I have this `img` element where I use [src] to dynamically create a path to this uploads folder to retrieve this image of a bear.

My question is now: Is this the correct way to do this or does this leave me vulnerable to security issues? And if so, what would be a better way to handle this?

**on the left side you see the uploads folder of the backend, right side how I create this file**

[image]

**html code (angular)**

```
<img [src]="linkImg(post.fileName)">
```

**component method: this method returns a url that will display the image. Is this the right way to do this or is this lacking security?**

```
linkImg(fileName) {
// base_URL returns localhost:3000 or the production URL
    return `${this.BASE_URL}/uploads/${posterProfilePic}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good way to handle the serve images. Keep in mind your server should be secure.

In case you want to protect the images for public display you need to make them secure through a middleware or any of the server technique and checking is an authenticated request or not.

From angular side it is good.

A read for security
https://nodesource.com/blog/nine-security-tips-to-keep-express-from-getting-pwned/

Comment: Thanks. I also have specific case where the content of a post is an html string I receive from the database (so it's not possible to use angular code on it). In this html string there is an image element where the src attribute is hardcoded and  leads to an image in this uploads folder on the backend as well. Is this safe as well, or will this cause issues?

Comment: I guess its well enough safe as you are serving html.
Why not serving with innerHTML of angular? 
Just a thought.